QGIS Graphical Modeler: "Send a Warning" / "Send a Message" Algorithms Not Displaying Messages
I'm working with the graphical modeler and noticed the algorithms:
Send a Warning
Send a Message

I tried adding them to raise a message when the data is in the wrong format, but I can't figure out how to use them. No message is displayed, even when I add a message without any conditions.
In the log, it shows:
Préparation de l'algorithme : native:raisemessage_1
Exécution de Envoyer un message [4/37]
Paramètres en entrée:
{ CONDITION: 'test', MESSAGE: 'This is a message' }
Résultats :
{ }

It seems like the algorithm is executed, but I don't see any message.
Have you already worked with these algorithms ?

This looks like you've made it conditional on test, but the CONDITION field should be a thing that is either true or false:
{ CONDITION: 'test', MESSAGE: 'This is a message' }

If I set the CONDITION field to 1=0, which is always false, I don't get a message. If I set it to 1=1 (which is always true) or leave it blank I do get a message. In the processing output, warnings appear red, and messages appear black. Here's the text (uncoloured because cut/paste doesn't do colours here):
Running Raise warning [1/2]
Input Parameters:
{ CONDITION: '', MESSAGE: 'Danger will robinson!' }
Danger will robinson!
Results:
{ }
OK. Execution took 0.021 s (0 output(s)).

Note that the message only appears (or doesn't appear) in the output text of the model - I don't see it in any of QGIS' log panels, if that's where you were expecting it. Appearing with all the other clutter of the output text is probably not a good idea, it gets lost easily.  If you use the "Advanced" button to reduce the logging level you'll see less clutter but still see the messages.
Sending a message to a QGIS log window might be a useful addition to the modelling toolbox...

I was indeed expecting to display a message in order to warn / inform the user of something (like the colored ones we have on QGIS). But if it only appears in the logs, it will not be helpful.

Yes, like I said in the last line, that's not what this does. Try adding your idea as a feature request on the QGIS web site.
